# Prestashop, allow_url_fopen, white screen

Tags: php, settings, prestashop, fopen

Got some trouble with php settings, but can  not solve it myself, need a help.

Prestashop 1.6.0.14 When allow_url_fopen is "On" can not load admin interface, got a white screen of admin login page. An error reporting returns nothing, the blank white page only.

The scripting protocol returns:

```
334","(Warning) Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Admin_dir/index.php:34)"
```

But these are warnings only, and back office must work.

When i disabled allow_url_fopen, the back office is workable, but without a lot of administrative functions, the allow_url_fopen option must be "On".

I have changed permissions to 0777 for a test, for all Prestashop root directory in all of depth, got a similar result.

The cache (/cache/smarty/cache & cache/smarty/compile) cleared manualy.

The memory_limit option (php.ini) is 256 Mb.

There is only one php.ini file on my system, without some recursions or jails.

I have restored all from the working backup for a test, got the similar result.

Obviously, a problem is in a PHP settings or in extensions. But cannot found it myself. Please, HELP!!!

[View info() PHP information](http://rgho.st/7p2SlbDMJ)

Comment: Have you tried turning debugging "on"?

Answer (score 0):

It solved
The automatic cache purification  shell script  sets a wrong permissions of cache dirs.
It was fogotten.